# flutter pub upgrade failing

Tags: flutter, upgrade

flutter pub upgrade

```
Git error. Command: git rev-list --max-count=1 android-x
fatal: ambiguous argument 'android-x': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
pub upgrade failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
```

I've tried both stable and beta channels with the same results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the problem.
I had a package in the pub spec that used a git path and ref:.
The project maintainers had deleted the branch so the ref was no longer valid.
Unfortunately the flutter error gave no hint of the package.